# trying to figure out how to add GestureDetectorCompat to my project

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-support-library

I'm reading the android documentation on handling common gestures. I've created an instance of `GestureDetectorCompat` in my main activity but this particular class doesn't seem to be recognized in the activity. I tried adding this line to my dependencies in `build.gradle` of my package but still I'm not having any joy.

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+"
```

I'm not too sure what is happening here as I thought when I added this line in the dependencies the option to use `GestureDetectorcompat` would become available? Also my min SDK is set to  15 and my target SDK is 19. I'm wondering is this preventing me from using `GestureDetectorCompat`? Any clarification you can provide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have already found the solution by now but posting the answer for others.

This is a three step solution based on using Android Studio:

1) Add "import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;" to the Java source file

2) Copy "android-support-v4.jar" from "\sdk\extras\android\support\v4" folder to "libs" folder in your app.

3) In Android Studio, right click on "app->libs->android-support-v4.jar" and choose "Add As Library..." option.

These steps should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd solved the same issue:

In Android Studio, Go to **File > Invalidate Caches / Restart**, select **Invalidate and Restart**.